# How to stay on Debian buster

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, repository

I originally installed Debian stretch, which at the time was "stable". I needed some newer packages that it didn't have, so I upgraded to Debian testing, which was buster. Currently my `lsb_release -a` command returns Debian 10 (buster).

It seems that recently Debian changed its packages so now I get a message from Synaptic:

```
Repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable' to 'oldstable'
This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Repository 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing InRelease' changed its 'Codename' value from 'buster' to 'bullseye'
```

Ok, makes sense. However, I don't want to upgrade to bullseye yet. I want to stay on buster, and when I decide to upgrade to bullseye, I'll do so manually. How should I edit my repos to accomplish this? Currently my repos look like this:

```
$ grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb cdrom:[Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 9.9.0 cinnamon 2019-04-27T11:50]/ stretch main 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb cdrom:[Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 9.9.0 cinnamon 2019-04-27T11:50]/ stretch main 
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main non-free contrib 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main non-free contrib 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/base.list:deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/base.list:# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/base.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/base.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/base.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/base.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/base.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/base.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:hawkeye116477:waterfox.list:deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/hawkeye116477:/waterfox/Debian_9.0/ /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:manuelschneid3r.list:deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/Debian_9.0/ /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x stretch main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x stretch main
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to change `testing` to `buster` in sources.list, but be sure to remove base.list, since it still points to Stretch.

The `home:hawkeye116477:waterfox.list` and `home:manuelschneid3r.list` still point to Stretch (Debian 9.0), but check with the corresponding upstreams to see what is the right URL for Buster (Debian 10.0).

Finally, check the Node documentation and correct the URL for `deb.nodesource.com`

Answer (score 1):

You can merge `sources.list` and the `base.list` :

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/base.list
```

then edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

add the new keys:

```
wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:hawkeye116477:waterfox/Debian_10/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:manuelschneid3r/Debian_10/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
```

edit `home:hawkeye116477:waterfox.list` and `home:manuelschneid3r.list` then change `Debian_9.0` with `Debian_10`.

change `stretch` with `buster`  under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list` then run:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

[Example sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list)

[home:manuelschneid3r project](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:manuelschneid3r&package=albert)

[home:hawkeye116477:waterfox project](https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3Ahawkeye116477%3Awaterfox&package=waterfox)